# What is the purpose of llvm::make_unique?

Tags: c++, llvm

In llvm's compiler implementation tutorial (e.g. [here](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl02.html)) `llvm::make_unique` is used. What is the reason they aren't using `std::make_unique`? I wasn't able to find any clear documentation on this.

Comment: Maybe because `std::make_unique` didn't exist in C++11

Comment: @Praetorian I completely overlooked that. Makes sense.

Comment: @Praetorian, seeing as that apparently solved the question, could you actually post that as an answer?

Comment: In the current version of the tutorial they appear to use both, I'm assuming it's a mistake?: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl02.html

Comment: I would think so. They don't seem to be compiling with C++14.

Comment: LLVM moved to C++14 in 2019 and now uses std::make_unique().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

LLVM is written using C++11 conforming code while [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is a C++14 feature. So if they want `make_unique` they need to implement it.

#### Details

If we go to the [LLVM Coding Standards](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html) the [C++ Standard Versions section](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#c-standard-versions) says:

> LLVM, Clang, and LLD are **currently written using C++11 conforming code**, although we restrict ourselves to features which are available in the major toolchains supported as host compilers. The LLDB project is even more aggressive in the set of host compilers supported and thus uses still more features. Regardless of the supported features, code is expected to (when reasonable) be standard, portable, and modern C++11 code. We avoid unnecessary vendor-specific extensions, etc.

We can see from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) that `std::make_unique` is a C++14 feature.  If they want to use `make_unique` then they can't use the std version.

We can see from a recent [llvm-dev discussion](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2018-May/123182.html) that moving to C++14 is still an open subject.

Comment: just remind that recently they adapted C++14 and replaced `llvm::make_unique` with `std::make_unique` - https://reviews.llvm.org/D66259